# Simple Android Image Parsing

Tags: java, android, json, url, bitmap

I'm attempting to parse image URLs and show the images in a ListView, but I continue to receive the ProtocalNotFound Exception/JSON Exception No value for null.  I am pretty sure I'm close to translating the image URLs into bitmaps, but I'm off by something small.  Any ideas for the right approach would be helpful.  My class is below including the URL for the feed.  Right now, I'm trying to convert the image URL in the loadImageFromWebOperations method.  Please let me know if you need more information.

Android Class:

```
public class mainViewController extends ListFragment 
{

    mainViewController context = this;

    // Progress Dialog
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        // testing on Emulator:
        //private static final String READ_COMMENTS_URL = "https://shipstudent.com/androidapp/comments.php";
        private static final String READ_COMMENTS_URL = "https://shipstudent.com/complaint_desk/androidcentralwall.php";

        // JSON IDS:
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
        private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
        private static final String TAG_POSTS = "posts";
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private static final String TAG_POST_ID = "IDPosts";
        private static final String TAG_USERNAME = "username";
        private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "body";
        private static final String TAG_PROFILE_PICTURE = "profile_picture";
        //private static final String TAG_POSTED = "posted";

        // it's important to note that the message is both in the parent branch of
        // our JSON tree that displays a "Post Available" or a "No Post Available"
        // message,
        // and there is also a message for each individual post, listed under the
        // "posts"
        // category, that displays what the user typed as their message.

        // An array of all of our comments
        private JSONArray allPosts = null;
        // manages all of our comments in a list.
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mCommentList;

    public mainViewController()
    {
    }

    String[] mainFeed = {};

     @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

//       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//          ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
//                  inflater.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
//                  mainFeed);
//
//          setListAdapter(adapter);


         return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
     }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onResume();
            // loading the comments via AsyncTask
            new LoadComments().execute();
        }

        public void addComment(View v) {
//          Intent i = new Intent(ReadComments.this, writePostViewController.class);
//          startActivity(i);
        }

        /**
         * Retrieves recent post data from the server.
         */
        public void updateJSONdata() {


            mCommentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(READ_COMMENTS_URL);

            try {

                allPosts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);

                // looping through all posts according to the json object returned
                for (int i = 0; i < allPosts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = allPosts.getJSONObject(i);

                    // gets the content of each tag
                    String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                    String content = c.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                    String username = c.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
                    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    String profile_picture = c.getString(loadImageFromWebOperations(TAG_PROFILE_PICTURE.replaceAll(" ", "%20"),sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/dir1/dir2"));
//                  String profile_picture = c.getString(TAG_PROFILE_PICTURE);
                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                    map.put(TAG_MESSAGE, content);
                    map.put(TAG_USERNAME, username);
                    map.put(TAG_PROFILE_PICTURE, profile_picture);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    mCommentList.add(map);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }



        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        public static String loadImageFromWebOperations(String url, String path) {
            try {
                InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();

                System.out.println(path);
                File f = new File(path);

                f.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                try {

                    byte[] b = new byte[100];
                    int l = 0;
                    while ((l = is.read(b)) != -1)
                        fos.write(b, 0, l);

                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

                return f.getAbsolutePath();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exc=" + e);
                return null;

            }
        }

        /**
         * Inserts the parsed data into the listview.
         */
        private void updateList() {
            // For a ListActivity we need to set the List Adapter, and in order to do
            //that, we need to create a ListAdapter.  This SimpleAdapter,
            //will utilize our updated Hashmapped ArrayList, 
            //use our single_post xml template for each item in our list,
            //and place the appropriate info from the list to the
            //correct GUI id.  Order is important here.
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this.getActivity(), mCommentList,
                    R.layout.single_post, new String[] { TAG_TITLE, TAG_MESSAGE,
                            TAG_USERNAME, TAG_PROFILE_PICTURE }, new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.message,
                            R.id.username ,R.id.imageView1});

            // I shouldn't have to comment on this one:
            setListAdapter(adapter);

            // Optional: when the user clicks a list item we 
            //could do something.  However, we will choose
            //to do nothing...
            ListView lv = getListView();    
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                    // This method is triggered if an item is click within our
                    // list. For our example we won't be using this, but
                    // it is useful to know in real life applications.

                }
            });
        }


        public class LoadComments extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
//              pDialog = new ProgressDialog(mainViewController.this);
//              pDialog.setMessage("Loading Posts...");
//              pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
//              pDialog.setCancelable(true);
//              pDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                updateJSONdata();
                return null;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                //pDialog.dismiss();
                updateList();
            }
        }

     @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        }
}
```

Logcat:

```
09-08 21:29:01.281: I/System.out(17363): Exc=java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: profile_picture
09-08 21:29:01.281: W/System.err(17363): org.json.JSONException: No value for null
09-08 21:29:01.321: W/System.err(17363):    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
09-08 21:29:01.321: W/System.err(17363):    at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:515)
09-08 21:29:01.321: W/System.err(17363):    at com.rynovation.kline.mainViewController.updateJSONdata(mainViewController.java:128)
09-08 21:29:01.321: W/System.err(17363):    at com.rynovation.kline.mainViewController$LoadComments.doInBackground(mainViewController.java:230)
09-08 21:29:01.371: W/System.err(17363):    at com.rynovation.kline.mainViewController$LoadComments.doInBackground(mainViewController.java:1)
09-08 21:29:01.371: W/System.err(17363):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
09-08 21:29:01.371: W/System.err(17363):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
09-08 21:29:01.371: W/System.err(17363):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
09-08 21:29:01.371: W/System.err(17363):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-08 21:29:01.371: W/System.err(17363):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-08 21:29:01.371: W/System.err(17363):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here
String profile_picture = c.getString(loadImageFromWebOperations(TAG_PROFILE_PICTURE.replaceAll(" ", "%20"),sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/dir1/dir2"));

First get they value for key and then load the url.

Comment: Would you happen to have an example?  I'm beyond lost.